# Plotting several random trials in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, reshape2

I am currently running a simulation using a normal distribution, it simulates the times between events and is based on an analysis of data given (not relevant for the problem). The simulation is created like this:

```
SimProcess <- function(mu, sigma, T) {

  ctimes <- c()  # Array of arrival times, initially empty
  t <- rnorm(1,mu, sqrt(sigma)) # Time of next arrival
  while(t < T) {
    ctimes <- c(ctimes, t)
    dt = rnorm(1, mu, sqrt(sigma))
    if (dt<0){dt = 0}
    t <- t + dt # sampling from the dataset
  }
  return(ctimes)
}

# Create a sample path of one run
T <- 10
# arrival times
arrivals <- SimProcess(mu_t, var_t, T)
```

Now I would like to do several of these random trials and then plot them in a figure so we can compare it to the given data. 10 of these trials would be ideal. I tried plotting it like this but unfortunately it doesn't work. I am afraid i'll have to use reshape2 to melt the data of the 10 trials because the length of these vectors is all not the same. I use this to try to plot all the lines, it clearly doesn't work the way it should.

```
x <- c(0, arrivals, T,rep(0,500-length(arrivals)))
y <- c(0:length(arrivals), length(arrivals),rep(0,500-length(arrivals)))
plotdataNT = data.frame(x,y)
p = ggplot(plotdataNT,aes(x,y))
plot(x,y,type = 's')
j = 1
for (j in 10){
  arrivals <- SimProcess(mu_t,var_t,T)
  x <- c(0, arrivals, T,rep(0,500-length(arrivals)))
  y <- c(0:length(arrivals), length(arrivals),rep(0,500-length(arrivals)))
  p = p + geom_step(mapping = aes (x,y))
}
```

Edit: 
In the end I figuered it out, because I used 10 instead of 1:10 it would not run properly and I also had some more tiny mistakes. This ended up being the solution:

```
arrivals <- SimProcess(mu_t,var_t,T)
NT <- length(arrivals)
x <- c(0, arrivals, T,rep(0,correction-length(arrivals)))
y <- c(0:length(arrivals), length(arrivals),rep(0,correction-length(arrivals)))
plotdataNT = data.frame(x,y)
p = ggplot(plotdataNT,aes(x,y)) + geom_step(mapping = aes (x,y)) 
jk = 1
runs = 25
colourvec = rainbow(runs)
for (jk in 1:runs){
  arrivals <- SimProcess(mu_t,var_t,T)
  x <- c(0, arrivals, T,rep(0,correction-length(arrivals)))
  y <- c(0:length(arrivals), length(arrivals),rep(0,correction-length(arrivals)))
  newdata  = data.frame(x,y)
  p = p + geom_step(mapping = aes (x,y),newdata,colour = colourvec[jk])
}
p = p + scale_x_continuous(name = "Time in days") + scale_y_continuous(name = "Amount of claims")
p
```

This results in 26 random samples plotted in one graph in several colors, it represents a process with random time steps according to the gamma, normal or lognormal distribution. The answer below is a more clean example of what I meant. If anyone knows how to do this with reshape2 in a more efficient way I'd also be glad to know.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - what does that mean? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

```
for (j in 1:10) {
  arrivals <- SimProcess(mu_t,var_t,T)
  x <- c(0, arrivals, T,rep(0,500-length(arrivals)))
  y <- c(0:length(arrivals), length(arrivals),rep(0,500-length(arrivals)))
  xy <- data.frame(x,y)
  p = p + geom_step(data=xy, mapping=aes(x,y))
}
print(p)
```

[image]

```
for (j in 1:10) {
  arrivals <- SimProcess(mu_t,var_t,T)
  x <- c(0, arrivals, T,rep(0,500-length(arrivals)))
  y <- c(0:length(arrivals), length(arrivals),rep(0,500-length(arrivals)))
  xy <- data.frame(x,y)
  p = p + geom_step(mapping=aes_string(x,y))
}
print(p)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, in the end I implemented it like this and it worked out fine ideed!